# How do I properly finish basement without framing?

Tags: drywall, waterproofing, moisture, basement-refinishing, basement-insulation

Here is the issue: we have an unfinished laundry room and an unfinished closet. I would like to finish both of them. We are in a wet/moisture climate (Wisconsin). I am trying to do this without framing - hoping I can do some sort of waterproofing+furrough stripping+drywall. The walls in our laundry room were completely painted with some sort of moisture barrier/sealer prior to purchase purchase.

So I’ve done some research. I think I know what I need to do, but looking for pointers and any further input or recommendations. From what I am seeing, the process is as follows:

Boarded insulation directly to the block wall

Moisture/vapor barrier

Furring strips 24” apart with masonry or tapcon screws

Affix drywall to furring strips

The basement areas to be done are not currently framed or have footings. Not sure if this NEEDS to be done or if I can just start with the above listed steps without framing.

I have done some home drywall before but was not attached to cinder block. If I decided to add insulation, how would I ago about this? Do they make a moisture/vapor barrier that is like a ‘board’ similar to insulation board that would just be applied first? Would love any info from people who have done this before - and preferably people who are in the trades. Thanks!

Comment: Do you plan to [install]|[accommodate any existing] electrical services?

Comment: "The basement areas to be done are not currently framed or have footings." What does this mean, in particular the "or have footings" part? Also, please [edit] to focus on one thing in this question. Feel free to post several questions, just not all in one - it's how we work here. Take the [tour] and read through [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: *Boarded insulation* - what is that? Foam boards? Not a good idea from a fire-safety standpoint - fiberglass or many other things would be safer.

Comment: Paint on the interior existing wall does not guarantee future performance. A polyethylene barrier applied to the face of the inside wall at grade and below and tied into a vapor barrier on the interior face should be considered. Joints should be sealed with acoustic sealant.

Answer (score 3):

*As I sit here in the unfinished half of my basement...*

If you want to put up drywall, you really need proper framing. Since this framing doesn't need to support much, it could be a bit thinner than a standard 2x4 wall (nominal 1.5" x 3.5"). However, the usual 2x4 wall structure has some significant benefits over thinner structures:

- 3-1/2" available for insulation
- The bottom plate is attached to the floor. The top plate is attached above. The studs are attached to the bottom and top plates but do *not* need to be attached to the existing walls.
- Electrical and plumbing can be run *inside* the walls in standard ways. Furring strips will probably be OK for electrical, almost certainly not deep enough for plumbing.
- Standard electrical boxes can be used for switches, receptacles, etc.
- Studs can be used to mount shelving or other things.